# Trying to separate the year month and day fields via RegEx

Tags: regex, alteryx

I have a series of dates that I am trying to separate into years, months and days.  These dates are in the yyyy-mm-dd format.  I'm not very familiar with RegEx, but I have tried `(\dddd)\-(\dd)\-(\dd)`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What means -  *"to separate* `yyyy-mm-dd` *into years, months and days"*?

Comment: I am trying to parse the years, months and day of each cell into its own cell.  The accepted answer from Engineero did the trick.

Comment: `d` matches `d`, `\d` matches digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepted answer would also match invalid dates like 1234-56-78, or if mm & dd were in the wrong positions.

```
([1-2][0-9]{3})\-([0-1][0-9])\-([0-3][0-9])
```

Does a little more validation.